# How can I get element value in JSON file could be nested with Jmespath?

Tags: json, python-3.x, jmespath

I have a JSON file that shows the hierarchy filesystem. For parsing JSON files I choose Jmespath to pars and get data. below JSON file could be nested. I want to select File name based on hierarchy.

```
{
    "/home/user/Desktop/test_for_chain_click/test": [
        {
            "name": "file1",
            "permission": "0664",
            "type": "file"
        },
        {
            "/home/user/Desktop/test_for_chain_click/test/directory1": [
                {
                    "name": "file2",
                    "permission": "0664",
                    "type": "file"
                },
                {
                    "name": "file3",
                    "permission": "0664",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "name": "directory1",
            "type": "directory"
        },
        {
            "/home/user/Desktop/test_for_chain_click/test/directory2": [
                {
                    "name": "file4",
                    "permission": "0664",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            ],
            "name": "directory2",
            "type": "directory"
        }
    ],
    "name": "test",
    "type": "directory"
}
```

How Can I get file name with Jmespath on a file that could be nested?

Comment: What do you mean by _based on hierarchy_?

Comment: I mean like a tree hierarchy filesystem. Are you understand or I give an example?

Comment: Please have a read on [ask], if you have a desired behaviour (ouput), it should be part of your question. So, yes, you should [edit] it accordingly.